# I am getting an undefined index error

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I am getting these errors:

Notice: Undefined index: first_name in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Assesment/add_student.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined index: last_name in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Assesment/add_student.php on line 14

Notice: Undefined index: age in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Assesment/add_student.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined index: mobile in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Assesment/add_student.php on line 16

Notice: Undefined index: email in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Assesment/add_student.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined index: address in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Assesment/add_student.php on line 18

Notice: Undefined index: club_role in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Assesment/add_student.php on line 19
Error: Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'

Here is my code:`

```
    <h1> Add a new student</h1>
    <p>Add a new student to the system using the form below</p>

    <?php

    /*information posted from booking form*/
    $first_name=$_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name=$_POST['last_name'];
    $age=$_POST['age'];
    $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $address=$_POST['address'];
    $club_role=$_POST['club_role'];


    /*connect to DBMS*/
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    if (!$con)
    {
        die ('Could not connect: ' .mysql_error());
    }

    /*connect to Database*/
    mysql_select_db("91368_jurgen_glee",$con);

    /*insert into records*/
    $sql="INSERT INTO glee (`first_name`, `last_name`, `age`, `mobile`, `email`, `address`, `club_role`)
    VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$age', '$mobile', '$email', '$address', '$club_role')";

    mysql_Query($sql, $con) or die ('Error: '.mysql_error());

    $result=mysql_query("SELECT *
        WHERE `first_name` = '$first_name'
        AND `last_name` = '$last_name'
        AND `age` = '$age'
        AND `mobile` = '$mobile'
        AND `email` = '$email'
        AND `address` = '$address' 
        AND `club_role` = $club_role'");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($reslut))

    /*close DBMS Connection*/
    mysql_close($con);

    ?>
```

`

and here is the html code:`

```
                <div id="body"> 
                    <h1> Add a new student</h1>
                    <p>Add a new student to the system using the form below</p>

                    <form name="add_student" action="add_student.php">

                        <table class="add_student">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="form">
                                    <b>First Name</b></br>
                                    <input type="text" name="first_name" size="30" value="">
                                </td>

                                <td class="form">
                                    <b>Last Name</b></br>
                                    <input type="text" name="last_name" size="30" value="">
                                </td>
                            </tr>   
                            <tr>
                                <td class="form">
                                    <b>Mobile</b></br> 
                                    <input type="text" size="10" name="mobile" min="1" max="10" value="">
                                </td>

                                <td class="form">
                                    <b>Email</b></br>
                                    <input type="text" name="email" size="15" value="">
                                </td>

                                <td class="form">
                                    <b>Age</b></br>
                                    <input type="number" name="age" size="2" min="1" max="30" value="">
                                </td>
                            </tr>



                                    <td class="form">
                                        <br>
                                    </h1><b>Address</b></h1>
                                    <select name="address">
                                        <option value="01">Please select one</option>
                                        <option value="02">Red Beach</option>
                                        <option value="03">Orewa</option>
                                        <option value="04">Silverdale</option>
                                        <option value="05">Dairy Flat</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <br>

                                    <td class="form">
                                        <br>
                                    </h1><b>Club Role</b></h1>
                                    <select name="club-role">
                                        <option value="01">Please select one</option>
                                        <option value="02">Lead</option>
                                        <option value="03">Backstage</option>
                                        <option value="04">Chorus</option>
                                        <option value="05">Orchestra</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>

                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" class="submit">
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
                                </td>
                            </tr>


                        </table>

                    </form>

            </div> 


            </div>
    </body> 
</html>
```

`

Comment: Can we see your HTML form please to match up with the $_POST inputs?

Comment: just added the HTML code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this notice because array `$_POST` does not have `first_name` key like another ones. They are going to appeared only when you make `POST request` like submit the form or make AJAX call.

## 1. One file for GET and POST request.

In your snippet I can see you have one *.php file for `GET` method and `POST` method. To avoid this situation you can make two different files: `indexPost.php` and `index.php` and change HTML code:

```
<form action="indexPost.php" method="POST">
```

or make conditions to your keys:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['first_name']) && !empty($_POST['first_name'])) {
        // Your code
    }
?>
```

Each key needs own conditional statement.

## 2. Separate files for GET and POST request

If I'm wrong about one *.php file.

Using conditional statements (look on code above) remove all listed notices. Also you can improve it to validate form and mysql query.

## 3. Duplicate entry for key Primary

One of your column has primary key which can't be duplicated in one table. Let's say the column `last_name` has primary key. Then in whole table you can have only one row with value `LoremIpsum` in `last_name` column.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `method` to `POST` on the `form`, i.e.:

```
<form method="POST" name="add_student" action="add_student.php">
```

Comment: just added that and its still giving me the same errors

Comment: Are you posting any value inside `<input type="text" name="first_name" size="30" value="">` ? It doesn't seem so. Make sure you're posting any data.